# how to run an exe file on windows server from a website thats all?

Tags: php, windows, server, web, windows-server-2008

Hello all please help me with this i have a windows server which i can access with RDP and i can see the whole windows xp i have a exe file in "c" drive there under the folder name exe and i want to run it when i click on a button of a website.

The site is on php and it is on different server i have all the rights of both the server .
I have no idea how to do it.
Like i can run that exe from the server by RDP with command prompt with this parameter like file.exe='test' but i have no idea how to do this from the website please give me anything which can help me out with this .

Comment: did you tried exec php function? http://php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
exec('md c:\temp\\'.$_GET['home_dir']);
```

take care to command injections

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more please ...
i need a little more info how to run this ?
i have the PHP site on linux server and the exe file is on windows server both are on different IPs.

And how to run this from button click